# Core-ajax in Polymer

Tags: ajax, polymer, web-component

I'm just beginner in using Web Components with Polymer. I use core-ajax but something was wrong. Please help me to fix the error which I have made.

```
<polymer-element name="x-ajax">
    <template>
        <core-ajax
            id='ajax'
            auto
            handleAs='json'
            url="http://api.istockvina.com/watchlist"
            response="{{response}}"
            on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"
            on-core-error="{{handleError}}"
            >
        </core-ajax>
        {{data}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            data: [],
            ready: function(){
                alert('ready');
            },
            handleError: function(){
                alert(JSON.stringify(this.$.ajax.error));
            },
            handleResponse: function(){
                alert('done');
                this.data = JSON.stringify(this.$.ajax.response);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer>
```

The error is `{"statusCode":0,"response":""}`. When I changed the link
`url="http://www.filltext.com"` the error does not happen. What did i've wrong?. Sorry if my english was too bad. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is violating [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Your desired server does not set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, which prevents browser from executing cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest`.

*Sidenote:* setting both `response` and `on-×××-response` is superfluous. The former is made to bind response to variable, the latter for setting handler for response.

Comment: Also make sure your url is actually responding with correct JSON structure. But `Same Origin Policy` is most likely your issue.

Comment: @ErikIsaksen I did check, it responds with perfect JSON.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the help. Maybe I can understand you. Is it the same as you access to link http://192.168.0.109/happy-family/user/ in the core-ajax, link must be used `url="http://192.169.0.109/happy-family/user/login.json"` and of course when website is http://localhost/happy-family/user/ ,then `url="http://localhost/happy-family/user/login.json"` ?

Comment: Of course, in case I have not set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Comment: @ChouNguyen In general, yes. I would suggest you to switch chrome developer console on: it shows errors and you’ll see what’s happened.